# E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'PWideChar'

Tags: delphi

So I am trying to use variables with ShellExecute but always get this error when compiling `[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(44): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'PWideChar'`

I only have 2 variables and they are both strings `ssid` and `pass`
The line where the error is: `ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/c netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=' + ssid 'key=' + pass, nil, HIDE_WINDOW);`

If you have noticed by now I am trying to make a program that uses cmd to set, stop and start a hotspot. If I use this line `ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/c netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=VirtualRouter key=12345678', nil, HIDE_WINDOW);` it works just fine.

Projects code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ShellAPI, StdCtrls;

type
  TSSID = class(TForm)
    lblSSID: TLabel;
    edtSSID: TEdit;
    lblPASS: TLabel;
    edtPASS: TEdit;
    btnConfig: TButton;
    btnStart: TButton;
    btnRestart: TButton;
    btnStop: TButton;
    lblname: TLabel;
    lblname2: TLabel;
    procedure btnConfigClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnRestartClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    ssid: String;
    pass: String;
  end;

var
  SSID: TSSID;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TSSID.btnConfigClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ssid := edtSSID.Text;
  pass := edtPASS.Text;
  lblname2. Caption := edtSSID.Text;
  ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/c netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=' + ssid 'key=' + pass, nil, HIDE_WINDOW);
end;

procedure TSSID.btnRestartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/c netsh wlan stop hostednetwork', nil, HIDE_WINDOW);
  ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/c netsh wlan start hostednetwork', nil, HIDE_WINDOW);

end;

procedure TSSID.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/c netsh wlan start hostednetwork', nil, HIDE_WINDOW);

end;

procedure TSSID.btnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/c netsh wlan stop hostednetwork', nil, HIDE_WINDOW);

end;

end.
```

Any help? Thx. and yes i am new at delphi so sorry if what i am trying to do wont work

Comment: Seems odd to drive this through `cmd.exe`, why not call `netsh.exe` directly. I know `ShellExecute` is convenient, but if you want to get any failure diagnostics you will have a better experience with `CreateProcess`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'/c netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=' + said 'key=' + pass
```

This misses a `+` and you really meant:

```
'/c netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=' + said + 'key=' + pass
```

This expression is of type string, but `ShellExecute` expects to be supplied an argument of type `PChar`. Convert your string to `PChar` like so:

```
PChar('/c netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=' + ssid + 'key=' + pass)
```

Comment: So I changed it to this now `ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', PChar('/c netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=' + ssid 'key=' + pass), nil, HIDE_WINDOW);` and now my problem is `[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(44): E2029 ')' expected but string constant found` Im still pretty new at delphi so sorry.

Comment: Yeah OK there was another mistake. Look closely at your original code. It is missing a + and see my updated answer. You could have worked this out if you had read the error message. Don't give up so easily!